# Generating cross-document URL fields in Logstash/ElasticSearch/Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have this situation in my ELK (latest versions as of 3/2015) solution:

- I have a few large, relatively static documents in an ES
- I have lots of smaller log entry documents being placed by Logstash into ES
- During the "stashing" of the log entry documents, I would like to be able to generate a URL field (based on an incoming log entry field value) which will allow browser navigation from the log entry document to related satic ES document.  I will be able to infer the static document's ES Id from information in the log entry.

I'm pretty new to ELK and don't know all the information that might be available in the logstash context.  Is there any way to achieve this without hard-coding infrastructure details (DNS names, ports, etc)?

Comment: In logstash, you can make a new field for the URL based on the information from the log data.  That's probably too much hardcoding for you, though.  An upcoming version of kibana will have "formatters" which should help.